# Samba CentOS 6.5 cannot connect to the shared folder

Tags: linux, centos, network-shares, samba

The problem is that I added samba user 'root' via 'smbpasswd -a root'. Then I edited '/etc/samba/smb.conf' and added there:

```
[shared_folder]
valid users = root
public = no
path = /tmp
printable = no
writable = yes
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
```

After that I was able to connect via 'smb://ip/' with user 'root' and password.
But I saw that I can see not only '/tmp', but also the home directory of 'root' (/root). I am a newby in Linux, but I deemed that a bad idea, and I decided to redo that.

I added new user 'user1' both to the system and to samba. after that I edited my 'smb.conf', the string became 'valid users = user1'.

I also tried to remove user 'root' from samba with 'smbpasswd -x root', but got a message:

> Failed to delete entry for user root.

So, I went to '/etc/samba/smbusers' and commented 'root' there (by the way, no user 'user1' there!)

```
# Unix_name = SMB_name1 SMB_name2 ...
#root = administrator admin
nobody = guest pcguest smbguest
```

And tried to connect again. I am not able to connect with 'user1', but I am still able to connect with 'root'! and I see '/root' directory, not '/tmp' or both as before!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd try rebooting, or adding a new user, in case its cached in some way. Also this is a good time to consider using sudo, and learning/understanding that root is not to be trifled with ;)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  Yes, I rebooted, and of no avail, and I know about sudo. I was just in hurry, and now I regret about that...

Comment: By the way, I tried to do clean install of CentOS and not to add root but create new user from the beginning, so samba has new user that is not root. Still I am not able to connect with this user from my Mac.